# Different Terminal Windows, Same Location, Different Results?

Tags: bash, terminal, autotest, spork

Why when I run

```
$ autotest
```

In sample_app on my left terminal tab I get

> No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
>   ..

But in sample_app on my right terminal window I run

```
$ autotest
```

and get

> -bash: autotest: command not found

Can someone please explain this mystery to me?

Comment: Is the value of `$PATH` the same in both windows?

Comment: `autotest`is not a `bash` command.
Use `which autotest` in the working terminal to see which executable location is used, and try the same in nonworking terminal

Comment: @ Rajendra: One gave no response. The other told me its in my rails3tutorial gemset in the folder bin.  @Inderial: I tried PATH, but that does nothing, how do you check the value of path?

Comment: WHen I do $PATH I get: /Users/lasernite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin:/Users/lasernite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/Users/lasernite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/Users/lasernite/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory
and /Users/lasernite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/Users/lasernite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/Users/lasernite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/Users/lasernite/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin: No such file or directory
They appear to be the same

Answer (score 0):

The PATH is not the same in the two terminal sessions: The first directory in PATH is

```
/Users/lasernite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin
```

vs.

```
/Users/lasernite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin
```

- bring them into line and the sessions will behave alike.